# Is it possible to access Google Cloud Datastore API via gapi javascript client?

Tags: google-api-js-client, google-cloud-datastore

Does anyone have any example code for accessing google cloud datastore API using gapi javascript client? https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/overview

Answer (score 2):

```
var clientId = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';
var datasetId = '<YOUR_DATASET_ID>';
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore \
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email';
gapi.auth.authorize(
    {client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false},
    function(authResult) {
      if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        gapi.client.load('datastore', 'v1beta1', function() {
          gapi.client.datastore.datasets.beginTransaction({
            'datasetId': datasetId
          }).execute(function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
          });
        });
      }
    });
```

Keep in mind that since Google Cloud Datastore has no ACL support, the javascript client will have full read/write access to the whole dataset.

Comment: Has this changed since your answer 1 year ago? It's basically impossible to find documentation on this API for the javascript client library.

Comment: @mattdlockyer it looks as if you can commit to the datastore through the JSON API now. https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/datasets/commit